# Show divs based on the amount of arrays

Tags: php, arrays

Here is my function

```
function yyy_hero_image_option_callback() {
$hero_options = get_option( 'hero_options' ); 
$count=count($hero_options);
$totalimg=$count-4;
$html = '<div id="upload_yyy_sets">';
    for($i=1;$i<=$totalimg;$i++){ 
    if( isset( $hero_options['upload_yyy_link_1'] ) && $hero_options[ 'upload_yyy_link_1' ] ) { 
        $html .= '<div id="yyyclonedInput'.$i.'" class="yyyclonedInput">';
        $html .= '<input id="cs_product_menu_yyy_src_'.$i.'" type="text" size="36" name="hero_options[upload_yyy_link_'.$i.']" value="' . $hero_options['upload_yyy_link_'.$i.''] . '" /> <input id="cs_product_menu_yyy_src_'.$i.'_yyybutton" type="button" value="Add / Change" class="button-secondary yyy-upload-button"  /> <div class="button yyyremove">-</div>';
        $html .= '</div>';
    }
    }
    $html .= '</div>';

    echo $html;
    ?> <div class="button yyyclone">Add an Image</div> <?php 
}
```

Along with a little jquery, this worked out the amount of arrays, deleted the number by 4 and then displayed the amount of divs based on the resulting number. This has been working fine but now i've added another slideshow and it needs to be worked out differently.

Now here is my new function

```
function yyy_hero_image_option_callback() {
    $hero_options = get_option( 'hero_options' ); 
    foreach($hero_options as $key => $value){
        if (strpos($key, 'yyy')) {
            var_dump($value);
        }
    }
}
```

This new function just find the arrays that have the characters yyy in them.

How can I count the amount of arrays and then display them like before?

Thanks

UPDATE: Here's an image of what i'm trying to display

[image]

for every array that has the value zzz, i want it to display that amount of boxes, this image will show 3 boxes, that means there are 3 arrays with zzz in them.

Here's the array

```
array(9) { 
["show_hero_options"]=> string(1) "1" 
["hero_height"]=> string(5) "600px" 
["hero_width"]=> string(4) "100%" 
["hero_buttons"]=> string(4) "show" 
["upload_zzz_link_1"]=> string(105) "http://www.blahblah.com/image_link.jpg" 
["upload_zzz_link_2"]=> string(79) "http://www.blahblah.com/image_link.jpg" 
["upload_zzz_link_3"]=> string(79) "http://www.blahblah.com/image_link.jpg" 
["upload_yyy_link_1"]=> string(79) "http://www.blahblah.com/image_link.jpg" 

}
```

UPDATE 2a:

Here's the query just incase

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
// Hero Image zzz upload    
function zzz_updateClonedInput(index, element,param) {
    $(element).appendTo("#upload_zzz_sets").attr("id", "zzzclonedInput" +  index);
    $(element).find(">:first-child").attr("id", "cs_product_menu_zzz_src_" + index);
    $(element).find(">:first-child").attr("name", "hero_options[upload_zzz_link_" + index + "]");
    if(param)
    $(element).find(">:first-child").attr("value", "");
    $(element).find(">:first-child").next().attr("id", "cs_product_menu_zzz_src_" + index + "_zzzbutton");
}

$(document).on("click", ".zzzclone", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var zzztoappend='<div id="zzzclonedInput1" class="zzzclonedInput"><input id="cs_product_menu_zzz_src_1" type="text" size="36" name="hero_options[upload_zzz_link_1]" value="" /><input id="cs_product_menu_zzz_src_1_zzzbutton" type="button" value="Add / Change" class="button-secondary zzz-upload-button" /><div class="button zzzremove">-</div>'
    if( $(".zzzclonedInput").length < 1){
        // create div
        $('#upload_zzz_sets').append(zzztoappend);
    }
    else {
        // clone div
        var zzzcloneIndex = $(".zzzclonedInput").length + 1;
        var zzznew_Input = $(this).closest('.zzzclonedInput').length ? $(this).closest('.zzzclonedInput').clone() : $(".zzzclonedInput:last").clone();
        zzz_updateClonedInput(zzzcloneIndex, zzznew_Input,true); 
    }   
});

$(document).on("click", ".zzzremove", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents(".zzzclonedInput").remove();
    $(".zzzclonedInput").each( function (zzzcloneIndex, zzzclonedElement) {
        zzz_updateClonedInput(zzzcloneIndex + 1, zzzclonedElement,false);
    })
});

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(document).on("click", ".zzz-upload-button", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        upload_image($(this));
        return false; 
    });
});

function upload_image(el){
    var $ = jQuery;
    var custom_uploader;
    var button = $(el);
    var id = button.attr('id').replace('_zzzbutton', '');
    if (custom_uploader) {
        custom_uploader.open();
        return;
    }
    //Extend the wp.media object
    custom_uploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
        title: 'Add Image',
        button: { text: 'Add Image' },
        multiple: false
    });
    //When a file is selected, grab the URL and set it as the text field's value
    custom_uploader.on('select', function() {
        attachment = custom_uploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
        $('#'+id).val(attachment.url);
        $('#'+id).prev().attr('src', attachment.url);
        //console.log(attachment);
        console.log(id);
        //custom_uploader.close();
    });
    //Open the uploader dialog
    custom_uploader.open();
}

});
```

UPDATE 2b:

I've also managed to display the right amount of fields, it just doesn't add the value. Here's my new code

```
function tl_hero_image_option_callback() {
$hero_options = get_option( 'hero_options' ); 


foreach ($hero_options as $key => $value) {
if (strpos($key, '_zzz_')) {
    $html = '<div id="upload_zzz_sets">';

    if( isset( $hero_options['upload_zzz_link_1'] ) && $hero_options[ 'upload_zzz_link_1' ] ) { 
        $html .= '<div id="zzzclonedInput'.$i.'" class="zzzclonedInput">';
        $html .= '<input id="cs_product_menu_zzz_src_'.$i.'" type="text" size="36" name="hero_options[upload_zzz_link_'.$i.']" value="' . $hero_options['upload_zzz_link_'.$i.''] . '" /> <input id="cs_product_menu_zzz_src_'.$i.'_zzzbutton" type="button" value="Add / Change" class="button-secondary zzz-upload-button"  /> <div class="button zzzremove">-</div>';
        $html .= '</div>';
    }

    $html .= '</div>';

    echo $html;
}

} 


}
```

Comment: what do you want at all, please share an image form the result what you need

Comment: Added an image of what i'm trying to achieve.

Comment: I will give you an answer now (ITGW): do you want this at all: **for every array that has the value zzz, i want it to display that amount of boxes, yet image will show 3 boxes, that means there are 3 arrays with zzz in them**

Comment: That would be great thanks, i've just posted the array up as well.

Comment: you dont want YYY in there? does jquery need the count?

Comment: @david no, I just want to show the zzz, i've updated the code again see updates 2a and 2b. I now have it showing the right amount of boxes, it's just not adding the values, I know it's something todo with for($i=1;$i<=$totalimg;$i++){ } but I can't figure it out. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
function yyy_hero_image_option_callback() {

  $hero_options = get_option( 'hero_options' ); 
  $i=1;
  $html = '<div id="upload_zzz_sets">';

  foreach($hero_options as $key => $values){
    if (strpos($key, 'zzz')) { 
        $html .= '<div id="zzzclonedInput'.$i.'" class="zzzclonedInput">';
    $html .= '<input id="cs_product_menu_zzz_src_'.$i.'" type="text" size="36" name="hero_options[upload_zzz_link_'.$i.']" value="' . $values . '" /> <input id="cs_product_menu_zzz_src_'.$i.'_zzzbutton" type="button" value="Add / Change" class="button-secondary zzz-upload-button"  /> <div class="button zzzremove">-</div>';
    $html .= '</div>';
     $i++;

    }


  }

  $html .= '</div><div class="button zzzclone">Add an Image</div>';

  echo $html; 
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the updated code, it seems to be working fine although the values are getting replaced with h?

Comment: apologies, forgot to remove the key you were using, it should work now!

Comment: OK, so we're getting there, it seems to work fine when you upload 3 images, once you upload a 4th it starts to play up. When you click add / change and upload an image, you go to wordpress and choose the image, the value of that images then goes into the box, on the 4th time it doesn't, if you then save the page you're left with 3 boxes and the first field is empty which should of been image 1, any ideas?

Comment: the saving issue will be a php function to save the fields, is the code above in your functions.php file? Ill have a look at the jquery now...

Comment: Sorry to be a pain the the *** and thank you. There was also one other thing i noticed, on the original file when you deleted an image, the next image in line would take it's place, i.e if I deleted zzz_1, zzz_2 and zzz_3 would then become zzz_1 and zzz_2

Comment: try the php above now!

Comment: Hi David, it seems to be working almost perfect so far, i'm just playing about with different scenarios now but all looks good, I have noticed one thing, when you add an image it starts from 0, can this start from 1?

Comment: Hi, I just did that as I thought that would be the case and i've continued to test it and it's working great. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The way you changed your code, `$i` is not set anymore, try this :

```
foreach ($hero_options as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($key, '_zzz_')) {
        $i = substr($key, -1); // This will retrieve the last char of $key, which is corresponding to your previous $i
        $html = '<div id="upload_zzz_sets">';
        $html .= '<div id="zzzclonedInput'.$i.'" class="zzzclonedInput">';
        $html .= '<input id="cs_product_menu_zzz_src_'.$i.'" type="text" size="36" name="' . $value . '" value="' . $value . '" /> <input id="cs_product_menu_zzz_src_'.$i.'_zzzbutton" type="button" value="Add / Change" class="button-secondary zzz-upload-button"  /> <div class="button zzzremove">-</div>';
        $html .= '</div>';
        $html .= '</div>';
        echo $html;
    }
}
```

I also replaced the `$hero_options[key]` parts by `$value`, since you already get it from the foreach.